# tweet = textblob(tweet) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, textblob

```
tweet = textblob(tweet)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I have this problem while trying to run a sentiment analysis script. I have installed textblob with the following commands:

```
$ pip install -U textblob
$ python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

the code is the following:

```
import json
import csv
from textblob import TextBlob


#set the input and outputing file
input_file= "tweets.json"
output_file= "results.csv"

#store all json data
tweets_novartis = []

with open (input_file) as input_novartis:
    for line in input_novartis:
        tweets_novartis.append(json.loads(line))

#open output file to store the results
with open(output_file, "w") as output_novartis:
    writer = csv.writer(output_novartis)

    #iterate through all the tweets
    for tweets_novartis in tweets_novartis:
        tweet = tweets_novartis["full_text"]

        #TextBlob to calculate sentiment
tweet = Textblob(tweet)
tweet = tweet.replace("\n" , " ")
tweet = tweet.replace("\r" , " ")

sentiment = [[tweet.sentiment.polarity]]
writer.writerows(sentiment)
```

Comment: Please show us how you came to `textblob`.

Answer (score 1):

`textblob` as a package is not callable, hence we import the `TextBlob` object from `textblob` package.

```
from textblob import TextBlob

b = TextBlob('i hate to go to school')
print(b.sentiment)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `TextBlob` from `textblob` module

```
from textblob import TextBlob
tweet = TextBlob(tweet)
```

**From the Docs:**

```
>>> from textblob import TextBlob
>>> wiki = TextBlob("Python is a high-level, general-purpose programming language.")
```

**[More info](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html)**

Comment: import csv
from textblob import TextBlob


#set the input and outputing file
input_file= "tweets.json"
output_file= "results.csv"

#store all json data
tweets_novartis = []

with open (input_file) as input_novartis:
    for line in input_novartis:
        tweets_novartis.append(json.loads(line))

#open output file to store the results
with open(output_file, "w") as output_novartis:
    writer = csv.writer(output_novartis)

Comment: #iterate through all the tweets
    for tweets_novartis in tweets_novartis:
        tweet = tweets_novartis["full_text"]

        #TextBlob to calculate sentiment
        tweet = textblob(tweet)

        tweet = tweet.replace("\n" , " ")
        tweet = tweet.replace("\r" , " ")

        sentiment = [[tweet.sentiment.polarity]]
        writer.writerows(sentiment)

Comment: textblob is case sensitive it should be TextBlob

Comment: tweet = textblob(tweet)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "textsen.py", line 3, in <module>
    from textblob import TextBlob
  File "C:\Users\Ilia Gouma\Desktop\social web project\textblob.py", line 26, in <module>
    tweet = textblob(tweet)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Do you have a file called textblob.py in your dir?

Comment: if so change that to text_blob.py

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "textsen.py", line 26, in <module>
    tweet = Textblob(tweet)
NameError: name 'Textblob' is not defined

Comment: 'C:\Users\Ilia Gouma\Desktop\social web project\textblob.py' you renamed this file right?

Comment: any other idea?

Comment: Do you have any other file named "textblob.py". Because that is a core file of textblob module.

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "textsen.py", line 26, in <module>
    tweet = Textblob(tweet)
NameError: name 'Textblob' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Python is case sensitive. Use this:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
tweet = TextBlob(tweet)
```

**python != vba**

Comment: No You didn't. what you did was `from textblob` only looking into your traceback. try it again.

Comment: import csv
from textblob import TextBlob


#set the input and outputing file
input_file= "tweets.json"
output_file= "results.csv"

#store all json data
tweets_novartis = []

with open (input_file) as input_novartis:
    for line in input_novartis:
        tweets_novartis.append(json.loads(line))

Comment: #open output file to store the results
with open(output_file, "w") as output_novartis:
    writer = csv.writer(output_novartis)

    #iterate through all the tweets
    for tweets_novartis in tweets_novartis:
        tweet = tweets_novartis["full_text"]

        #TextBlob to calculate sentiment
        tweet = textblob(tweet)

        tweet = tweet.replace("\n" , " ")
        tweet = tweet.replace("\r" , " ")

        sentiment = [[tweet.sentiment.polarity]]
        writer.writerows(sentiment)

Comment: But you need to use `TextBlob(tweet)` instead of `textblob(tweet)`. python is case sensitive.